# Reverse for 'car_details' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['carscars/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/car_details\\Z']

Tags: django, django-templates

stackoverflow
`*`

```
`
In views.py
def car_details(request, id):
    single_car = get_object_or_404(Car, pk=id),
    # id = 1
    data = {
        'single_car': single_car,
        # 'url': url,
    }
    # reverse('single_car', args=(id))

    return render(request, 'cars/car_details.html', data)
In urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.cars, name='cars'),    
    path('<int:id>', views.car_details, name='car_details'),
]

In car.html
{% for car in cars %}
 <div class="detail">
                                <h1 class="title">
                                    <a href="{% url 'car_details' car.id %}">{{car.car_title}}</a>
                                </h1>
                                <div class="location">
                                    <a href="{% url 'car_details' car.id %}">
                                        <i class="flaticon-pin"></i>{{car.state}}, {{car.city}}
                                    </a>
                                </div>
{% endfor %}
In models.py
class Car(models.Model):
 id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,default=True)   
 also tried with revrser function on views.py it gives same error
``*`

 also tried with revrsere function on views.py it gives same error
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `pk` keyword argument in your route, as the error suggests.

You try to assign `pk` here:

```html
<a href="{% url 'car_details' pk=car.id %}">{{car.car_title}}</a>
```

But that'll throw an error because your route has one keyword argument `id` and NOT `pk`:

```py
path('<int:id>/car_details', views.car_details, name='car_details'),
```

Change it to this:

```html
<a href="{% url 'car_details' car.id %}">{{car.car_title}}</a>
```